How to upgrade from tfs 2015 to azure DevOps 2022 version?
I am trying to upgrade current tfs version from 2015. Do we have the link to upgrade from tfs version from 2015 to version 2022

You can check the general information and tips for upgrading Azure DevOps Server in the official document Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server.
Luckly, direct upgrades from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Server 2022 are supported.
The general upgrade process is as follows:

Prior to upgrading to Azure DevOps Server 2022, review the requirements provided in this article to ensure your current setup meets the system requirements.
Make sure you have a complete and consistent set of database backups available.
It's recommended to delete not-needed projects, artifacts, pipelines...etc. to shrink the database can speed up your upgrade (backup your database before the operation to prevent deleting something by mistaken).
Do the upgrade. After you finish your preparation, install the new version. Get the binaries and run through the installation process to upgrade your servers. Here is the download page.


Thanks for the information,will try this

Hi @GeethaHassan, glad to help you, and good luck with your upgrade. Looking forward to hearing your update.
